# The Data Source Configuration Wizard in C#

Tags: c#, database-connection

The Data Source Configuration Wizard is not opening in visual studio 2013 so I can choose a Database Model. It has a result that I can create tables, but that option is not showing on the shortcut menu.
How can I fix this or is there a way around it by setting up the database model manually?